# Reference for proof of Rigid Topological Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

Where can I find the proof of the following theorem:

> Let $M$ be a compact manifold such
>   that $K\geq 0$. Then there is an exact sequence
>   $$0\to \Phi \to \pi_1(M) \to B\to 0$$
>   where $\Phi$ is a finite group and $\bf B$ is a crystallographic group on $\Bbb R^k$ for some
>   $k\leq \dim M$.

I would be greatly appreciate if someone provide link of a book or paper for proof and similar theorems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in

J. Cheeger and D. Gromoll, On the structure of complete manifolds of nonnegative curvature,Ann. of Math. 96 (1972) 413–443.

Wilking proved a generalization of this result to manifolds with $Ric\ge 0$ in

On fundamental groups of manifolds of nonnegative curvature, 
Differential Geometry and its Applications, 13 (2000) 129–165

Comment: Thank you very much. So,  there is no difference between $K\geq 0$ and $Ric \geq 0$ in general?

Comment: In general, there is, but not for this particular question.

Comment: I checked the first paper, but I couldn't find the exact theorem! Can you please give me the exact address?

Comment: @C.F.G: Theorem 9.3 of Cheeger-Gromoll; Theorem 2.1 of Wilking.